# How to Dynamically Update a Sheets Custom Menu with Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to Dynamically Update a Sheets Custom Menu with Typescript

I have implemented the following: [Dynamically Updating Custom Menu of Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/1232a8fd1ffbd84c96ebbb97051c5b59) a sample script for dynamically updating the custom menu of Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.

but in Typescript there is an exception  when clicking the menu item: `Script function not found: Col1`

Is there something else that is required with typescript?

Main.ts

```
import { CustomMenu } from './ui/CustomMenu'

function onOpen() {
  CustomMenu.createMenu()
}
```

Main.gs

```
// Compiled using ts2gas 3.6.5 (TypeScript 4.3.2)
var exports = exports || {};
var module = module || { exports: exports };
//import { CustomMenu } from './ui/CustomMenu'
function onOpen() {
    //var menu = Menu.createMenu('Tracker')
    var menu = CustomMenu.createMenu();
}
```

CustomMenu.ts

```
export module CustomMenu {

  export function createMenu() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator();
    var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Sub-menu');
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var dynamicMenu = headers[i];
      this[dynamicMenu] = dynamicItem(i);
      subMenu.addItem(dynamicMenu, dynamicMenu);
    }
    menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
  }
}

function dynamicItem(i) {
  return function() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(2, i + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).activate();
  }
}
```

CustomMenu.gs

```
// Compiled using ts2gas 3.6.5 (TypeScript 4.3.2)
var exports = exports || {};
var module = module || { exports: exports };
exports.CustomMenu = void 0;
var CustomMenu;
(function (CustomMenu) {
    function createMenu() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
        var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
            .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
            .addSeparator();
        var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Sub-menu');
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            var dynamicMenu = headers[i];
            this[dynamicMenu] = dynamicItem(i);
            subMenu.addItem(dynamicMenu, dynamicMenu);
        }
        menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
    }
    CustomMenu.createMenu = createMenu;
})(CustomMenu = CustomMenu || (CustomMenu = {}));
function dynamicItem(i) {
    return function () {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getRange(2, i + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).activate();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I thought that in your script, when the menu of `Col1` is run, the function is not created.
- Also, I thought that the reason of your issue is due to `this[dynamicMenu] = dynamicItem(i);`.

  - I think that in your situation, `this` in the function cannot be used for installing the functions.

By above situation, the error of `Script function not found: Col1` occurs. So, in order to avoid this issue for your current script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this answer, I modified your script as follows.

##### `Main.ts`:

```js
import { CustomMenu } from './ui/CustomMenu'

function onOpen() {
  CustomMenu.createMenu(this)
}

CustomMenu.createMenu(this)
```

- `CustomMenu.createMenu(this)` out of the function `onOpen` is run, when the function is run from the custom menu. By this, the function is dynamically created.

##### `CustomMenu.ts`:

```js
export module CustomMenu {

  export function createMenu(obj) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var headers = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator();
    var subMenu = ui.createMenu('Sub-menu');
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      var dynamicMenu = headers[i];
      obj[dynamicMenu] = dynamicItem(i);
      subMenu.addItem(dynamicMenu, dynamicMenu);
    }
    menu.addSubMenu(subMenu).addToUi();
  }
}

function dynamicItem(i) {
  return function() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(2, i + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding the 2nd `CustomMenu.createMenu(this)` generates run time error: **Google Apps Script: ReferenceError: CustomMenu is not defined.** Custom Menu is not displayed.

Comment: @dak Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested the modified typescript, no error occurs. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the compiled Google Apps Script for replicating the issue of `Google Apps Script: ReferenceError: CustomMenu is not defined.` in your question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to compile the Google Apps Script. Could you please provide the steps required or reference to compile the Google Apps Script. Thanks.

Comment: @dak Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In that case, please provide `Main.gs` and `CustomMenu.gs`, reflected my proposed script, on Google Apps Script project instead of `Main.ts` and `CustomMenu.ts`. Unfortunately, when I tested my modified script, no error occurs. When "Col1" is run, the rows of "Col1" are activated. So I cannot still replicate your situation of `Google Apps Script: ReferenceError: CustomMenu is not defined.`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: I found the issue. This is my project structure with sub folders: `src/main.gs` and `src/ui/CustomMenu.gs`. With a flat structure, i.e. moving `main.gs and CustomMenu.gs` to root) the script worked.  How to make the script work with the original project structure `src/ui/CustomMenu.gs`?

Comment: @dak Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `How to make the script work with the original project structure src/ui/CustomMenu.gs?`, in this case, please move `CustomMenu.createMenu(this)` which is placed as the global (This is not in `onOpen()`.) in `Main.ts` to `CustomMenu.ts` as the global and test it again. By this, in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked.